# Jenkins check which plugins are not being used

Tags: jenkins

I have over 150+ plugins installed on Jenkins and was wondering how to (running Jenkins Console Script maybe?) find the plugins that are not being used at all. Is there a way to get a list like that?

EDIT: I found [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=73532011) plugin, although it shows only ~half of all plugins how many jobs use it, the other half is ignored and not showed if they are being used

Answer (score 0):

It is hard question.

Plugin usage plugin shows you list of plugins and number of jobs, which are using these plugins. But there is a feature - plugins have some dependent plugins, which could not be used by jobs. If you delete them - main plugins will stop work.

So my advice is not to delete plugins.

You can only delete plugins, which have the same functionality.

Better to clean workspaces, prune docker and system itself.